# what exactly is JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I am learning the REST architecture these days. I have developed many small small projetcs using jersey. My question is what exaclty is JAX_RS ? I understand that JAX-RS is a set of interfaces (all the **javax.ws.rs.* classes**) which contains annotations like GET,POST and a lot more. Jersey is one of the bundle which has classes which implement those methods. My doubt is if we download java , do the JAX_RS interfaces come with that ? I have used maven to build REST. There i have seen a lot of entries being added to pom which does my job, but i want to get the actual feel of what exactly is this JAX-RS. Any help is appreciated ! sorry if this is foolish !

Comment: Your question is too broad. You have too many unclear things: Maven, Rest, Java seem everything unclear to you. Java is a programming language (how it works you can find also in a specification), Maven simply build your applications, by compiling classes and making jar files, Jax-RS is for supporting RESTful requests (so that it is easy for developers to process such requests).

Comment: i understand what is java and what is maven, but what fail to understand is that are the GET,POST and all the likes just interfaces  part of javax.* package and jersey and Restlet etc provide implementations for that ?

Answer (score 2):

JAX-RS is just a specification. A specification specifies how such a framework should work (in a PDF file), and provides different Java interfaces and annotations and enums (like `javax.ws.rs.*` classes), but no functional code. 
The URL for JAX-RS specification are:

- JAX-RS 1.1 (you probably use this one) https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311
- JAX-RS 2.0 https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339

Along with the specification there are implementations of that specification, which is functional code (java jars), that you can use in your applications. Such implementations are JERSEY and RestEasy (usually applications use only one).

Now what you need is a JAX-RS tutorial. Take the first two results from google:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html (I find this one very good)
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html (this one is very comprehensive, IMHO)

Comment: you mean to say that the annnotations are part of Java ? i dnt have to download extra jars for that ? this line is confusing me "JAX-RS is a Java programming language API designed to make it easy to develop applications that use the REST architecture."